# gnuplot timestamp conversion

Tags: csv, graph, gnuplot

```
set y range [0:]

Set timestamp format for x-axis
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"  # Specify the input time format as Unix timestamp
set xlabel "Time"


set format x "\n%d/%m/%y\n%H:%M"  # Use \n for newline


set timestamp "\n%d/%m/%y\n%H:%M" at graph 0.5,0.02 font "Helvetica"


plot "C:/Users/dhaval_tarapra/Desktop/Code/2degree/Kalt_extracted_values.csv" using ($2):4 with lines title 'Your Data'
```

DATA IN CSV FILE:

```
[1] frame.number,[2] frame.time,[3] EV_MaximumVoltageLimit,[4] EVSE_MaximumVoltageLimit,[5] EV_MaximumCurrentLimit,[6] EVSE_MaximumCurrentLimit,[7] EVSE_PresentVoltage,[8] v2gdin.present.voltage,[9] EV_TargetVoltage,[10] v2gdin.target.voltage,[11] EVSE_PresentCurrent,[12] v2gdin.present.current,[13] EV_TargetCurrent,[14] v2gdin.target.current

4165,1324055753,4640,,5000,,,,4640,464,,,1190,119
4168,1324055753,,469,,11910,4022,402.2,,,11900,119,,
4171,1324055753,4640,,5000,,,,4640,464,,,1190,119
4173,1324055753,,469,,11910,4022,402.2,,,11900,119,,
4178,1324055753,4640,,5000,,,,4640,464,,,1190,119
4180,1324055753,,469,,11910,4025,402.5,,,11899,118.99,,
```

I used above script and got a below graph. On x Axis there are a time starting from 5:56 but in my .csv data file the time is starting from 6:56 so I want to set it. If any one have solution then please help me!

[image]

Comment: Please post a few lines of your data.

Comment: Please provide the data as text not as image. And please format your script and data within a pair of triple backquotes. Ok, your time in your datafile is in seconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00 UTC).

Comment: Thanks for providing data in text form. However, with the first timestamp `print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",1324055753)` returns `2011-12-16 17:15`. How should we investigate your problem if you don't provide the real data?

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show data and I don't know which timezone you're in. Not sure if I understand your issue correctly, but I cannot reproduce that the time on the x-axis is shifted by 1 hour relative to the time in the datafile.

But if the issue is about the timestamp, there are apparently different ways to place a timestamp somewhere on the graph. Check `help timestamp`, `help time`, `help strftime`.

From the documentation (`help time/date`)

> The conversion to and from seconds assumes Universal Time (which is
> the same as Greenwich Standard Time). There is no provision for
> changing the time zone or for daylight savings. If all your data refer
> to the same time zone (and are all either daylight or standard) you
> don't need to worry about these things. But if the absolute time is
> crucial for your application, you'll need to convert to UT yourself.

But then I don't understand and it hasn't yet become clear to me from the documentation why in the example below `timestamp` shows `08:22` and with `time()` and `strftime()` it shows `07:22`. I'm confused whether it takes UT (GMT) time or local PC system time. (By the way, I'm in timezone GMT+1 and on Windows. Not sure if the latter might also play a role).

Anyway, you can shift it, e.g. by 7 hours via adding `7*3600`seconds to `time(0)`. So, I would suggest to place the timestamp via `set label` and `strftime()` and adding the offset you need.

**Script.:**

```
### different ways of placing a timestamp
reset session

myTimeFmt = "%d/%m/%y\n%H:%M"

set timestamp myTimeFmt
set label 1 strftime(myTimeFmt,time(0))        at graph 0.5, graph 0.7
set label 2     time(myTimeFmt)                at graph 0.5, graph 0.5
set label 3 strftime(myTimeFmt,time(0)+7*3600) at graph 0.5, graph 0.3

plot x**2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]